C++ Kokkos passing list of functors as argument to a function
I have functors defined as follows-
struct f1{
    KOKKOS_INLINE_FUNCTION
    void operator()() const{
        printf("Functor 1\n");
    }; 
};

struct f2{
    KOKKOS_INLINE_FUNCTION
    void operator()() const{
        printf("Functor 2\n");
    }; 
};

I need to pass a list of these functors as an argument to a function, such that this list of functors can be used in a Kokkos environment.
I have done the same for a host environment without using Kokkos, using a vector of function pointers with the functions defined as follows-
void f1()
{
    printf("Function 1\n");
}

void f2()
{
    printf("Function 2\n");
}

I have created an array of function pointers as follows-
std::vector<void(*)()> f_list;
f_list.push_back(&f1);
f_list.push_back(&f2);

This list is passed as an argument to a function defined as follows-
void function(std::vector<void(*)()> f_list)
{
    ....
    ....
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(auto f: f_list){
        *f();
        }
    }
    ....
    ....
}

I am trying to parallelize the outer loop of this function using the Kokkos library. How can I pass a similar list, of functors defined above, such that it can be run in a Kokkos environment?

You can use a captureless lambda? That will also save you some typing. A captureless lambda can be converted to a function pointer. See demo

Or you can use std::function<void()>. That will work with functors, function pointers, lambda etc.

You probably have rather limited number of functions, in which case you don't need the overhead of vector or function and use tuple of callable objects, like this:
std::tuple f_list{
    f1{}, f2{},
    []{ printf("lambda 1\n");},
    []{ printf("lambda 2\n");}
};

and then iteration can also be changed to invoke each function from a tuple:
void function(auto&& f_list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("cycle %i\n", i);
        apply([](auto&&...fn){
            (std::invoke(fn), ...);
        }, f_list);
    }
}

Here is a Compiler Explorer example


How can I pass a similar list, of functors defined above, such that it can be run in a Kokkos environment?

Method 1
You can use std::function as shown below:
struct f1{
    
    void operator()() const{
        printf("Functor 1\n");
    }; 
};

struct f2{

    void operator()() const{
        printf("Functor 2\n");
    }; 
};
void func()
{
    
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> f_list;
    f_list.push_back(f1());
    f_list.push_back(f2());
    f_list.push_back(&func);
    
}

Method 2
Better would be to use a captureless lambda(since they can be implicitly converted to a function pointer) as shown below. That will also save you some typing.
std::vector<void(*)()> f_list;
f_list.push_back([](){printf("Functor 1\n");});
f_list.push_back([](){printf("Functor 2\n");});

Working demo

A functor or non-static function cannot be converted to a pointer to function. It requires a conversion operator void(*)() which would involve some boilerplate code (which can be complex in a general case if you have some arguments or use it as template). It's easier to use captureless lambda or std::function, which already generates code, but if that's required for some particular well-known type, this is what required:
struct f1{
    void operator()() const{
        printf("Functor 1\n");
    }

    // this must be static to obtain the pointer
    static void f1_invoke() { f1()(); } 

    // function type (optional, for brevity)
    using f1ptr_t = void (*)();

    // conversion operator
    operator f1ptr_t () { return &f1_invoke; }
};

int main()
{
    f1 func;
    void (*func_ptr)() =  func;
}

